# configuring ramp-up in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Trying to figure this out

I have a single request, i'd like to send the request 100 times every 1 hour. in a loop

what is the right setup for this using the thread group plugin ?

Comment: thread group is no plugin, it is built-in. Should the 100 requests be run in parallel or after another ?

Comment: one after another @Marged

Comment: So please update your question so that we have all information in one place. Doing this you can update the tags too. To make this clear: there shall be one hour of inactivity between the 100 calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must combine these configuration:
- Number of thread (users) = 100
- Ramp-up Period = 3600

Those configuration will send request 100 times in 1 hour.

Loop Count will determine how many hours you want to run the test. If you wan to run the test for 10 hours, just set the loop to 10.

I hope this help you.